# How to set values to form elements at once?

Tags: angular

I have a form built using a FormBuilder with lots control elements and I want to set values to them based on response from server

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
this.form.controls['a'].setValue(data.a);
this.form.controls['b'].setValue(data.b);     
this.form.controls['c'].setValue(data.c);
this.form.controls['d'].setValue(data.d);
```

and so on.

Is there a way to do it more neat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setValue](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#setValue-anchor) of `FormGroup`.

According to the API docs.

> It accepts an object that matches the structure of the group, with
>   control names as keys.

You can do:

```
this.form.setValue({
   a:data.a,
   b:data.b,
   c:data.c,
   d:data.d
 });
```

You will need ensure all the control values are present together and they pass any `validators` you may have set for your form.

You could also use [patchValue](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#patchValue-anchor) function as suggested by @Gunther to fill your form. 
It can take subsets of form values without validation and tries to match them.

Comment: `patchValue` is similar but more forgiving for fields not matching controls.

Comment: Thanks.. But I though it was more of an update form functionality rather than set all values as OP is asking.Correct me if I am wrong on that